# adding a confirmation box to form submission with image

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I am using an image to submit a form. But I cannot get the form to show a confirm dialog before submitting.

I usually use the `onClick()` for this, but now as I am using it for the submit it is now working for me.

Is there anyway to make it work, so that it shows a confirm box before submitting?

```
<form style="margin-bottom: 0px;" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="doc_to_delete" value="{$documents[sec1].doc_id}" />
<img src="../images/action_images/delete.jpg" style="height: 20px;" title="Delete Document" onclick="submit();"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not submit in a submit button

Instead use `onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure')"`

like this

```
<form id="form1" onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure')" style="margin-bottom: 0px;" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="doc_to_delete" value="{$documents[sec1].doc_id}" />
<input type="image" src="../images/action_images/delete.jpg" style="height: 20px;" title="Delete Document" />
</form>
```

Better to not have the code inline:

```
window.onload=function() { 
  document.getElementById("form1").onsubmit=function() {
    return confirm('Are you sure');
  }
}
```

Comment: It does not check the `onsubmit()` when I click. It just immediately submits.

Comment: `any console errors? did you remove the click handler from the image? It should by the way be `<input type="image" src="........delete.jpg"/>`

Comment: I did not catch that part. Worked now like a charm :) Thank you

Comment: You are welcome. See update for full code and alternative to inline event handlers